# Laravel 5.4: How to securely track a selected item across page views?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm new to Laravel and building a site for multiple users which on one of it's pages lists items related to the logged in user, allowing the user to click on an item and then on the next page, view or edit the details. Very simple concept, but I'm wondering when the details page is served by Laravel, how to simply and securely know which item was clicked and display the details for the correct item.

The obvious way to solve this is just to specify the item's primary key ID in the URL for the details page - i.e. for each item in the list on the first page, and then specifying a route that uses that to return the correct item:

```
Route::get('/itemdetails/{ID}', 'MyController@showitemdetailspage');
```

then obviously using the specified ID to do a database lookup.
Trouble is, this is completely insecure, i.e. any user could try out different numbers in the ID field and access other user's item details.

So how I do this securely in Laravel in a way that a user can't spoof an ID etc?
I'm thinking something with sessions or a hash of the ID or something but not sure how to actually implement this.

As I'm new to this, source code or specific details much appreciated!

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything put in the URL as an identifier can be cracked, a hash of some sort can slow this down (significantly) but will not solve your problem, it would be better for you to use "proper" authentication.
Inside your controller you could check if the user has access to the specified page.

```
public function showitemdetailpage($ID){
    $someModel = MyModel::find($ID);
    if($someModel->user_id == Auth::user()->id){
        return view('myawesomeview', ['detail' => $someModel]);
    }
    abort(404);
}
```

I opted for an 404 error here to prevent other users from even finding out if an specified detailPage exists, you could also return a status code of `403` (not allowed). This would let other users know that the detail page exists but cannot be accessed by them.

By blocking the access instead of obfuscating the ID's you can be sure that nobody can access the page even if they do have the url (of course this only works if the authentication is implemented properly).

My example is only one way to check the authentication Laravel has an elaborate method of authorising people and actions by using their gates of which you can read more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization).

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are the best way to store this kind of information safely! You can add the value in session using `session()->put('key','value')`. It means you can do this to enter as many values as you want! It will store your Data safely as Laravel will store it in the file I think!

You can Clear the session values by removing everything except Login information ( `session()->forget('key')`) when you don't need the values in Specific Session or you can Store it in Array and remove the whole array when it is no Longer needed! I do the same to store the ID of the server in my system as one user can manage many servers!
Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Thanks but with sessions I don't see how I track what item the user clicked on (to have the server pull up the correct details record) and also how to prevent users accessing other user's item details that they're not authorised to see? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using built-in Laravel auth you can use a simple construct function at the top of your controller and remember to use `use Auth;`
and if it is a clean install you have to run also `php artisan make:auth`

```
use Auth;

class WhateverController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
         {
             $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => 'logout']);
         }

    ... Your Controller code
```

This will allow (except for the logout) the access only to auth (that in Laravel is set by default to users)

Comment: Thanks. That would ensure a details page is not viewable by a non-user (i.e. made public) but it wouldn't stop one user from viewing another user's details page - as both of them would be logged in/authorised.